# Pass value when form submitted to If function on another file

Tags: php, database

I have two different files.

Checkoutstep4.php

Checkoutstep5.php

When the first form is submitted, I want to take the value of 'country' which has been submitted and use it in an IF function:

This is what I have so far using session variable...
however I get an error saying undefined index and I am not sure why.

**checkoutDeliveryInfo (file that runs when the delivery details form is submitted).**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'DatabaseConnection.php';

$_SESSION['customerid'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO DeliveryDetails (customerid,firstname,lastname, addressline1, addressline2, city, county, country, postalcode)
            VALUES ({$_SESSION['customerid']}, :firstname, :lastname, :addressline1, :addressline2, :city, :county, :country, :postalcode)");

    $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':addressline1', $addressline1);
    $stmt->bindParam(':addressline2', $addressline2);
    $stmt->bindParam(':city', $city);
    $stmt->bindParam(':county', $county);
    $stmt->bindParam(':country', $country);
    $stmt->bindParam(':postalcode', $postalcode);


    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $addressline1 = $_POST['addressline1'];
    $addressline2 = $_POST['addressline2'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $county = $_POST['county'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $postalcode = $_POST['postalcode'];



    $stmt->execute();

    $_SESSION['country'] = $country;

    header('location:../View/php_shopping_cart/CheckoutStep5.php');
}
```

**IF function in the Checkoutstep5.php file where the session variable is being used:**

```
    <?php
    include '../../Model/ShoppingCart.php';
    $shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart;
    // redirect to home if cart is empty
    if ($shoppingCart->total_items() <= 0) {
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    }

    ?>
          <div class="shippingcost"><strong>Shipping Cost <?php
                                if ($_SESSION['country'] != 'GIB') {
                                    $shippingcost = '10.00';
                                } else {
                                    $shippingcost = 'FREE';
                                }
                                echo $shippingcost;
                                ?></strong>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Update: Error Message:

> Notice: Undefined index: country in /home/k1509759/www/barbarycoast/View/php_shopping_cart/CheckoutStep5.php on line 246

Comment: Do you have a `session_start()` somewhere in the step5-file? If not, it in the top of the file or your current session data won't be available.

Comment: Yes, in the file ../../Model/ShoppingCart.php a session is already being initiated...

<?php
session_start();

class ShoppingCart {

Comment: _"I get an error saying undefined index"_ - Can you update your question to include the exact error message?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson error message has been added.

Comment: The PHP code you have in question for `Checkoutstep5.php`, is that located in the middle of the file? Try moving it to the top of the file instead. `session_start()` and any `header()` declaration (like your header redirect) needs to be called before _any_ output is made.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you for your suggestion, however it still does not work.. :(

Comment: Do a var dump and check what the session contains in step5. Also, dump `session_status()` and check that it actually is started. Just have to ask, line 246 is your `if`-statement you've posted and not somewhere else? Your `ShoppingCart`-class doesn't do anything with sessions?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yep everything seems to be fine. would it be possible to convert a session variable into a normal one?

Comment: A session variable is a normal variable. It just happens to be super global (accessible from everywhere) and pre-populated.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you for your help and comments - I've managed to do it by extracting all variables from the session and then using the individual one i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do it by extracting all variables from the session and then using the individual one i wanted.

```
extract($_SESSION);

if ($country == 'GIB') {
    $shippingcost = 'FREE';
} else if ($country == 'GBR') {
    $shippingcost = '£10.00';
} else if ($country == 'ESP') {
    $shippingcost = '£10.00';
}
```

Comment: This solution makes no sense at all. 1. If you're not careful,`extract()` can give you some unwanted side effects (variable collision). 2. Adding a bunch of variables to the global namespace for no reason is seldom a good idea. 3. If this actually worked, then `$_SESSION['country']` should definitely have worked as well since all extract does, is making variables from array keys. So basically, if the `country`-key is undefined in the session, it can't create a variable called `$country`.